# Handling redirecting <301> from Indeed with Scrapy

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm building a person scraper for Indeed primarily to practice on - I've set it up so that I extract details per 100 results in each page. By using the search query, I have a seed-list of cities and types of jobs looped within an f-string of the indeed url. I have these results stored as a dictionary, so that I can get the degree types as a column when these results are read into pandas.

My issue is that I keep getting `Redirecting (301)`, I suppose that's because not all the links fulfil the requirement of a salary. Alternatively, I have included `meta={'handle_httpstatus_list': [301]}` but then I get no results regardless.

Here's my scraper:

```
class IndeedItem(scrapy.Item):
    job_title = Field(output_processor = TakeFirst())
    salary = Field(output_processor = TakeFirst())
    category = Field(output_processor = TakeFirst())
    company = Field(output_processor = TakeFirst())

class IndeedSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'indeed'
    max_results_per_city = 1000
    #names = pd.read_csv("indeed_names.csv")
    #degree = pd.read_csv("degree_names2.csv",encoding='unicode_escape')
    names = pd.DataFrame({'names':['London', 'Manchester']})
    degree = pd.DataFrame({'degrees':['degree+Finance+£25','degree+Engineering+£25'], 'degree_type':['Finance', 'Engineering']})
    start_urls = defaultdict(list)
    for city in names.names:
        for qualification,name in zip(degree.degrees, degree.degree_type):
            start_urls[name].append(f'https://uk.indeed.com/jobs?q={qualification}%2C000&l={city}&fromage=7&filter=0&limit=100')

    custom_settings = {
        'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/96.0.4664.110 Safari/537.36',
        'DOWNLOAD_DELAY':2
    }

    def start_requests(self):
        for category, url in self.start_urls.items():
            for link in url:
                yield scrapy.Request(
                    link, 
                    callback = self.parse,
                    #meta={'handle_httpstatus_list': [301]},
                    cb_kwargs = {
                        'page_count':0,
                        'category':category 
                }
            )

    def parse(self, response, page_count, category):
        if page_count > 30:
            return
        indeed = response.xpath('//div[@id="mosaic-zone-jobcards"]//div')
        for jobs in indeed:
            loader = ItemLoader(IndeedItem(), selector = jobs)
            loader.add_value('category', category)
            loader.add_xpath('job_title', './/h2[@class="jobTitle jobTitle-color-purple jobTitle-newJob"]/span//text()')
            loader.add_xpath('salary', './/div[@class="salary-snippet"]/span//text()')
            loader.add_xpath('company', './/a/div[@class="slider_container"]/div[@class="slider_list"]/div[@class="slider_item"]/div[@class="job_seen_beacon"]/table[@class="jobCard_mainContent"]/tbody/tr/td[@class="resultContent"]/div[@class="heading6 company_location tapItem-gutter"]/pre/span[@class="companyName"]//text()')
            yield loader.load_item
        
        next_page = response.xpath('//ul[@class="pagination-list"]/li[5]/a//@href').get()
        page_count += 1
        if next_page is not None:
            yield response.follow(
                next_page, 
                callback = self.parse,
                cb_kwargs = {
                    'page_count': page_count,
                    'category': category
                }
            )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't had any 301 status, but the start_urls gave me problems and your xpath was off

This fix the xpath:

```py
import scrapy
from pandas._libs.internals import defaultdict
from scrapy import Field
from scrapy.loader import ItemLoader
from scrapy.loader.processors import TakeFirst
import pandas as pd


class IndeedItem(scrapy.Item):
    job_title = Field(output_processor=TakeFirst())
    salary = Field(output_processor=TakeFirst())
    category = Field(output_processor=TakeFirst())
    company = Field(output_processor=TakeFirst())


class IndeedSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'indeed'

    custom_settings = {
        'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/96.0.4664.110 Safari/537.36',
        'DOWNLOAD_DELAY': 2
    }

    max_results_per_city = 1000
    # names = pd.read_csv("indeed_names.csv")
    # degree = pd.read_csv("degree_names2.csv",encoding='unicode_escape')
    names = pd.DataFrame({'names': ['London', 'Manchester']})
    degree = pd.DataFrame({'degrees': ['degree+Finance+£25,000', 'degree+Engineering+£25,000'], 'degree_type': ['Finance', 'Engineering']})

    start_urls = defaultdict(list)

    def start_requests(self):
        for city in self.names.names:
            for qualification, name in zip(self.degree.degrees, self.degree.degree_type):
                self.start_urls[name].append(f'https://uk.indeed.com/jobs?q={qualification}&l={city}&fromage=7&filter=0&limit=100')

        for category, url in self.start_urls.items():
            for link in url:
                yield scrapy.Request(
                    link,
                    callback=self.parse,
                    #meta={'handle_httpstatus_list': [301]},
                    cb_kwargs={
                        'page_count': 0,
                        'category': category
                    }
                )

    def parse(self, response, page_count, category):
        if page_count > 30:
            return
        indeed = response.xpath('//div[@class="slider_container"]')
        for jobs in indeed:
            loader = ItemLoader(IndeedItem(), selector=jobs)
            loader.add_value('category', category)
            loader.add_xpath('job_title', './/span[@title]//text()')
            loader.add_xpath('salary', './/div[@class="salary-snippet"]/span//text()')
            loader.add_xpath('company', './/span[@class="companyName"]//text()')
            yield loader.load_item()

        next_page = response.xpath('//ul[@class="pagination-list"]//li[last()]/a/@href').get()
        page_count += 1
        if next_page:
            yield response.follow(
                next_page,
                callback=self.parse,
                cb_kwargs={
                    'page_count': page_count,
                    'category': category
                }
            )
```

If you can give an example for a url that redirects I can try to help you.

Comment: I'm not sure as to why, but when I run my script I get `Redirecting (301)`, but with your updates, it works fine. I haven't thought of running the loop for url inside start_requests and then grab the urls outside of it. Pretty neat! I still need some practice with the xpaths, do you know of any good documents to brush up my skills?

Comment: I didn't use any xpath tutorial but I'm sure there are plenty.

Comment: After some while the website returns me to a captcha page; Might you perhaps know of any tricks to reduce this from happening? I've used `DOWNLOAD_DELAY` and a longer delay may help but it will take much longer to scrape.

Comment: @joe_bill.dollar check out [scrapy-rotating-proxies](https://pypi.org/project/scrapy-rotating-proxies/).